# Load single property of a class async

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm bulding a dynamic UI and I have a "ul" list that needs to load a single value from the db per "li". A sort of badge that display a count from the db.

Following is a bit of code:

```
function A {
    var count;
    function buildItem() {
        //some code to build a list "li" item
    };
    this.setCount = function(number) {
        count = number;
    };
    this.getHtml = function() {
        buildItem();
        return html;
    };
};

function B {
    var ul;
    var container = [];
    function loadCount(ref, i) {
        //ajax call that should set count for class A
        $.ajax({
            //blabla
            container[i].setCount(jsonResult);
        });
    };
    this.buildList = function() {
        //code that build the list..
    };
};
```

What I need is that `loadCount()` assign the value retrieved from the db before or at the same time the script is parsed. Using an asynchronous request populate the count after the list is displayed.

How can I populate my A class count with the value taken from the db and after display the entire list ?

Answer (score 0):

Hide your `ul` until you receive the counts for all your `li` elements. Display a loader during the time of loading.

```
var nResponses = 0;

$.ajax( "example.php" )

  .done(function(msg) {

     addLi(msg);                   //Add an li element to the ui

     if (liCount === nResponses)   //Check if all the responses are received. liCount is the number of lis you have
       showUl();                   //Everything is good. Show the ui  
     else
       nResponses++;               //Increase the response count  
  })
```

Comment: the ul should be shown at the end of all process throught a display() method.. I set the count for every item and than I build and show the ul

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: that the ul is still displayed with the default value (0) and not with the value retrived from the db.. The value is correctly loaded but is loaded after..

Comment: if I break the ajax call with an echo, I can display the ul correctly

Comment: This is because you are showing the ui without waiting for all the responses. You should check for the completion of requests in ajax.done function. Then display the ui if everything is good.

Comment: Ok I have used a solution similar to yours but I used a tmp[] array to trace every item in my list. I also modified my ajax call letting them building the entire item if not in the tmp[] array